# How to access to class method inside a Task?

Tags: c#, task

Suppose I have a class called `Foo` which have the following design:

```
public class Foo
{
    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
         await some method..
    }
}
```

I want create an array that contains different `Task<Foo>`, so I declared the following array:

```
Task<Foo>[] tasks = new Task<Foo>[10];
```

and then I assigned the array index for create the `Task<Foo>` in the following way:

```
 tasks[1] = new Task<Foo>();
```

Now I want access to the `StartAsync()` method, but when I write the following:

```
tasks[1].
```

I only have the `Start()` method which is the default method that start the task. How can I instead access to the `Foo` class methods?

Comment: A `Task<Foo>` means that at some point you have the result of some operation that gave you back a `Foo`. It does not mean that you have an asynchrounous `Foo`. This design approach seems weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd need an array of `Foo`s instead of `Task<Foo>`s

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[10];
```

Then you can do this:

```
foos[1] = new Foo();
await foos[1].StartAsync();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your tasks[1] object is actually a type of Task not Foo, in order to access to Foo, you need either await for it or using the result property of The Task

```
var foo = await tasks[1];
foo.StartAsync()

//Or

tasks[1].Result.StartAsync() //be careful with deadlock when you using Result.
```